# Controlling 5V Pushbutton switch fails with Triac

Tags: triac, switching, 5v

I have an external consumer product what I try to automate by connecting my Arduino to its push buttons. This device uses internally 5V, I can get this voltage on the switch buttons as well.

[image: push]

My goal would be to automate this without relays to keep my circuit small and quiet.

I have tried 2 methods so far:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Small-Triac-Switch/

-Connecting the buttons to the triac

-Connecting the buttons to the MOC directly

The results were the same. For the first time the switch works (device turns on) but any other attempts are ignored. I would like to understand why and how to modify my circuit to work possibly with the components I have on hand (TIC206 or MOC3041).

I got the triac in high power switching in mind because I didnt know what the device uses internally until I disassembled it but I would say the MOC should be good enough for switching 5V.

If I use a relay or just sort the wires by hand that works 100%.

[image: moc]

Answer (score 1):

You mention "TRIAC".

A TRIAC is a double thyristor and a thyristor is a switching transistor type device that you can switch ON by providing a current through it's gate but you can only switch it OFF if you **interrupt** the current that it is switching !

I think you are switching a DC signal (the 5 V you measure) so even if you turn the gate signal off (like you do) it will stay ON no matter what. TRIAC switches are for switching AC currents, not DC !

I suggest you get an optocoupler with a phototransistor, not one with a TRIAC / thyristor !

Answer (score 0):

A Triac with Zero-Cross detection works by turning an AC signal on or off at the Zero Crossing point. A DC signal does not have a Zero-Cross point.

You can use a dc optocoupler (4N35 is commonly used), or if you don't care or need isolation, a simple transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5j4Q6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is a simple pull-down to prevent a floating base from turning the transistor on.

Comment: Hello, please suggest some specific models I can buy from digikey/ebay then for optocoupler. Is there a stability issue with using regular npn transistors for switching? Is there a possibility the device can turn on due to some error? I would like to avoid that. With a relay there is no possibility for that, its either off or on. Thanks

Comment: The 4N35 is a common one for something like this. And no, a regular NPN wouldn't have any stability issues, as long as you don't leave the base floating. A Pull-Down resistor of 10~47kΩ from base to ground would do that. An Opto-coupler is basically an led with light sensitive transistor in a box anyway. @munin24

Answer (score 0):

The opto-triacs are intended for switching alternating current and are a poor choice for this application. You need to use a transistor type opto-isolator.

The two most likely swithing arrangements of your "external consumer product" are shown in Figure 1 and 2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2sbQB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figures 1, 2 and 3.*

A transistor type opto-isolator will work for either pull-up or pull-down circuit.

- Connect the opto-transistor collector to the positive side of the button.
- Connect the opto-transistor emitter to the negative side of the button.
- Connect the opto-LED as shown to your Arduino.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram, can't I use the MOC3041? It is supposed to be an opto isolator..

Comment: Fairchild say, " MOC3041M 6-Pin DIP 400V **Zero Crossing Triac Driver** Output Optocoupler" and I imagine they should know. Yes, it's an opto-isolator but as three of us have told you this is the wrong type of opto-isolator. It's for switching AC. You are switching DC.